# SwiftUI List not getting updated when `listRowInsets` are applied

Tags: swiftui-list, swiftui

## Goal

Update data in a `List` on tap

## Problem

When `.listRowInsets` are applied to the list rows, the list stops getting updates when the state changes.

## Code

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    private var array = ["a", "b", "c"]
    @State private var selectedIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        makeBody()
    }
    
    private func makeRow(_ t: String, index: Int) -> some View {
        return HStack {
            Text(t)
            Spacer()
            if selectedIndex == index {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
            }
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            print("selected \(index)")
            self.selectedIndex = index
        }
    }
    
    private func makeBody() -> some View {
        return List {
            ForEach(0..<array.count) { i in
                self.makeRow(self.array[i], index: i)
                    // comment and uncomment this line
                    // .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 16, leading: 20, bottom: 16, trailing: 20))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Question

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data can be changed, you need a dynamic `ForEach` loop (with an explicit `id` parameter):

```
ForEach(0..<array.count, id:\.self) { i in // <- add `id:\.self`
    self.makeRow(self.array[i], index: i)
         .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 16, leading: 20, bottom: 16, trailing: 20))
}
```

It's not well documented though. In some cases Xcode warns you when you try to modify your array used in a ForEach loop:

> `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data.
> Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)`
> and provide an explicit `id`!

Comment: That works! Do you have a source for that? I couldn't find anything regarding the `id` parameter and dynamic `ForEach`...

Comment: @youjin True, I couldn't find anything explicit in Apple documentation. Maybe I missed something. Anyway I added an Xcode warning which provides a good explanation.