# How should the viewModel object be declared in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, reactive-programming, combine

I am trying to use an @ObservableObject viewModel which is declared as @ObservedObject inside my view struct. The problem is that when the viewModel changes it's "domains" property @Published var, the UI is not updating. Also, I change domains inside getDomains() function which is called inside init() {}. Looks like it is called twice, why is that happening? Here's my code for viewModel:

```
import Combine

class DomainsViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var domains: [InterestDomain] = [InterestDomain]()
    
    init() {
        self.getDomains { (response) in
            print(response)
        }
    }
    
    func getDomains(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        NetworkEngine.shared.appNetwork.getInterestDomains { result in
            self.domains.removeAll()
            switch result {
            case .success(let domainsOfInterest):
                if let domainsList = domainsOfInterest {
                    self.domains = domainsList
                }
                completion(true)
            case .failure(_):
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Code for the view:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

```
struct DomainsOfInterestView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: DomainsViewModel = DomainsViewModel()
    
    @State var isActive = true
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Choose domains of interest for your profile")
                        .font(.headline)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.bottom, 16)
                
                ForEach(viewModel.domains.indices) { index in
                    DomainOfInterestElement(isActive: self.$isActive, domain: self.viewModel.domains[index].name)
                }

                OrangeButton(action: {
                }) {
                    Text("Save")
                }.padding(.top, 30)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 30)
                Spacer()
            }.padding([.leading, .trailing], 12)
            .navigationBarTitle("Domains of interest")
    }
}

struct DomainsOfInterestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
    DomainsOfInterestView()
    }
}

struct DomainOfInterestElement: View {
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    var domain: String
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isActive.toggle()
        }) {
            VStack {
                Divider().padding(.bottom, 12)
                HStack {
                    checkBoxView()
                        .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                    textView().font(.custom("SFProDisplay-Regular", size: 16))
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func checkBoxView() -> Image {
        switch isActive {
        case true:
            return Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "check-box-active-2-1")).renderingMode(.original)
        case false:
            return Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "check-box-active-1")).renderingMode(.original)
        }
    }
    func textView() -> Text {
        switch isActive {
        case true:
            return Text(domain)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        case false:
            return Text(domain)
                .foregroundColor(Color.orGrayColor)
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Besides the answers below, you might need to be careful with multiple threads. I can't see the code for the getInterestDomains, but it might be calling back in a background thread. Then changing the published var in background thread could cause undefined things to happen (like the view not updating as it should). You might need to dispatch back to the main queue. This is in addition to not initializing your viewModel in your view unless you are using a @StateObject.

Answer (score 1):

`DomainsOfInterestView` is recreated on every update of its view model. And you initialise the view model property with a new `DomainsViewModel` instance every time. A new view model will have the `domains` property set to `[InterestDomain]()` and `self.getDomains` will be called again.

First of all, better to inject the viewModel to `DomainsOfInterestView` in an initiailiser as @youjin wrote in a comment to the previous post. Also, you can use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject` if your minimum deployment target allows that. In this case, the `viewModel` property won't be reset every time the view is updated.

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI the `View` struct hierarchy is the view model already so you shouldn't be using view model objects.

`ForEach` is a `View` struct not a traditional for loop. Make your model `Identifiable` and change the `ForEach` to:

```
ForEach(fetcher.domains) { domain in
```

Also your fetcher needs to be `@StateObject` otherwise it is lost on every re-init of `DomainsOfInterestView`.

Your fetcher object is missing cancellation support. You can get that automatically by just removing the object and using the `.task` modifier instead, e.g.

```
.task {
    do {
        domains = try await NetworkEngine.shared.appNetwork.getInterestDomains()
    }
    catch {
        message = error.localizedDescription
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Quoting the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666863/swiftui-list-not-getting-updated-when-listrowinsets-are-applied)

If your data can be changed, you need a dynamic ForEach loop (with an explicit id parameter):

```swift
 ForEach(viewModel.domains.indices, id: \.self) { index in // <=
    // ...
 }
```

In some cases Xcode warns you when you try to modify your array used in a ForEach loop:

> ForEach(*:content:) should only be used for constant data. Instead conform data to Identifiable or use ForEach(*:id:content:) and provide an explicit id!

### Tested code

```swift
struct DomainsOfInterestView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: DomainsViewModel = DomainsViewModel()
    
    @State var isActive = true
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Choose domains of interest for your profile")
                        .font(.headline)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.bottom, 16)
                
                ForEach(viewModel.domains.indices, id: \.self) { index in // <=
                    Text(String(index))
                }

                Button(action: {
                }) {
                    Text("Save")
                }.padding(.top, 30)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 30)
                Spacer()
            }.padding([.leading, .trailing], 12)
            .navigationBarTitle("Domains of interest")
    }
}


class DomainsViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var domains: [Int] = [Int]()
    
    init() {
        self.getDomains { (response) in
            print(response)
        }
    }
    
    func getDomains(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.domains = [1,2,3,4,5]
            completion(true)
        }
    }

}
```

Tested with Xcode 12 beta 6 on iOS 14 beta 6

Comment: I added that, but anyway, the UI is not being updated. I use some mockDate, and the value of "domains" is changing when getDomains() is called inside init() in viewModel.

Comment: I added the code that I tested with, it worked fine

Comment: I think I've found the problem. Looks like getDomains() function is executing twice, I build a new project using just this view, and 1st time domains changes to an array of 3 values,  second  it goes on failure and makes the array empty before that. That's why don t see any changes on UI because it makes the array empty with a second call of the function. But I do not understand why it is called twice, even in other views it is the same. Looks like I do something wrong, but can't get it.thanks

Comment: That depends on where you placed `DomainOfInterestView`, because the view model is initialised whenever the `DomainOfInterestView` is initialized. You can solve this by passing `DomainsViewModel` as a dependency to `DomainOfInterestView`. i.e. `DomainOfInterestView(viewModel: DomainsViewModel)`